# How to update UIPageViewController's page control count

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIPageViewController` with a page control. In the delegate, I implement the following methods:

- `presentationCountForPageViewController:`
- `presentationIndexForPageViewController:`

This works well, but the total number of pages can change, and the number of dots displayed in the page control doesn't change in this case.

How do I tell the page view controller to call `presentationCountForPageViewController:` to update the total number of dots when this happens?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this was a result of using `NSFetchedResultsController` as the source of the data for pages. The count for `NSFetchedResultsController` was not getting updated before I called `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` on the `UIPageViewController`.

The fix was to call the following function in `controllerDidChangeContent:` to force an update to the page control.

```
func refreshPageController() {
    let controllers = pageController.viewControllers
    if controllers.count > 0 {
        pageController.setViewControllers(controllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Though the solution above worked, it broke the animation I was using to scroll to the next page when a page was removed.

A better solution: just wait until the page removal is committed to Core Data before calling `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the workaround I found is to reset the uipageviewcontroller view every time I change my dataSoure and reload the whole pageViewController with the new dataSource. This way I'm able to have the correct number of dots (with the dataSource and delegate functions correctly implemented). I do this with the following function :

```
func reloadPageViewController() {
    if pageContentView.subviews.count > 1 {
        for _ in 1...pageContentView.subviews.count - 1 {
            pageContentView.subviews.last?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    guard let pageViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: String(describing: PageViewController.self)) as? PageViewController else {
        return
    }

    pageViewController.removeFromParent()
    self.configurePageViewController()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `dataSource` property again to a new instance of a data source object that has the new number of objects.